# How to download a html generated by a javascript as pdf

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, printing, nokogiri, pdfkit

I want to save the html generated by a javascript on a website.

When I run the javascript, it returns me the html ready, with a button that link to the chrome printer, to save as pdf. I want to save this html genrated as a PDF, but I can't do it.

I've spent days triyng almos everything, PDFKit with Nokogiri Parsing, searched for a chrome printer API, etc, but nothing made it. Does anyone knows how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) and [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) can convert it.

Then just run the command

`phantomjs rasterize.js $URL_OR_PATH $PDF_OUT_FILENAME Letter`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the JavaScript you're running, figure out the URL it calls, along with whatever variables it adds to the GET/POST request, then use OpenURI or an HTTP client of some sort to request that file. Pass that to Nokogiri, and parse out the URL for the file.

The alternate is to use one of the WATIR gems to drive a browser, and access the file that way. Then you can retrieve the HTML, or have the browser retrieve the file, and get it off the disk when its done.

---

> I didn't understood the second solution you proposed, can you explain more?

Sometimes developers use Ajax to retrieve HTML and insert it into a page, or directly manipulate the page's HTML using JavaScript.

You can ask a Watir-driven browser to give you the current HTML and then parse it using Nokogiri or another XML parser, to retrieve things that are part of the HTML DOM at that moment. From there you can save that to disk and have the Watir-driven browser read it and render it. Then it's a matter of figuring out how to get the browser to print to PDF, or grab a snapshot of the screen to turn it into a PDF.

Comment: The first solution proposed does not work cause the link is not accesible in other ways other than the browser that send the request to the js, in this case, the browser of Watir.

I didn't understood the second solution you proposed, can you explain more?